# What happens when you pick up an item while affected by the Enlarge/Reduce spell?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, objects

The [*enlarge/reduce*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/enlarge-reduce) spell states:

> [...] If the target is a creature, everything it is wearing and carrying changes size with it. Any item dropped by an affected creature returns to normal size at once [...]
>
> **Reduce.** [...]  The target's weapons also shrink to match its new size. While these weapons are reduced, the target's attacks with them deal 1d4 less damage [...]

If the *enlarge/reduce* (choosing *reduce*) spell is cast on you, can you simply pick up a regular-sized weapon to avoid the 1d4 damage reduction? Alternatively, can the creature drop a *reduced* weapon, and then pick it back, removing the 1d4 damage reduction? In other words, what happens when a creature affected by *enlarge/reduce* picks up an item?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## The weapon remains normal size

Items picked up after the spell has been cast are not reduced. The weapon still has normal damage.

If you drop a Reduced item then it returns to normal size:

> Any item dropped by an affected creature returns to normal size at once.

However be aware that [Reduce](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/enlarge-reduce) makes you smaller: *"This reduction decreases its size by one category--from Medium to Small, for example."* So if you become small or smaller then a weapon with [heavy](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/equipment#WeaponProperties) property then it may not be an ideal: *"Small creatures have disadvantage on attack rolls with heavy weapons"*